# check for threads still running after program exits

Tags: c, pthreads

gcc 4.4.3 c89 pthreads

I use valgrind for checking memory errors.

I am just wondering if there is any tool for linux that can detect running threads that haven't been terminated after the program finishes.

I am running a multi-thread application and need a tool to make sure all threads have finished.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: As far as I can see your are posing two seperate questions. One is for the "debugger like" detection if there is still a thread running The other one is to ensure that all threads have finished when you end your `main`. Please be clearer for which you want to have an answer, and for which you propose the bounty

Comment: I'm not so sure how helpful such a tool would be.  If you are not going to wait for your threads to finish before exiting then you can never be sure if your process finishes before the threads are done.  You could run the tool once (or more) and see that all the threads finish before the process exits.  And then run the process again and all the threads don't finish before the process exits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the program has terminated (because the initial thread returned from `main()`, some thread called `exit()`, or a fatal signal was recieved by the process) then you are guaranteed that all threads have been terminated with extreme prejudice.

---

If you want to write your program so that it *ensures* that all its threads have exited before `main()` exits, then you need to loop over all your threads at the end of `main()`, calling `pthread_join()` on each one.  (This also means that you shouldn't create your threads detached, or detach them).

Comment: But child threads being terminated (with extreme prejudice) can be a problem. Thus as the last part of main() you want to try and get the child threads to exit (and wait for them to do so). Thus the question; Is there a way to check that this will not happen. exit() and signal() are a separate and harder case to solve.

Comment: @Martin York: The OP saying he wanted *"a tool to determine..."* made it sound like he wanted an external program to check if his program had finished exiting.

Comment: Yes, just some external tool. I always use valgrind to check memory leaks. I am just wondering if there was anything for doing the same for threads. Thanks.

Comment: @caf: There is no "need" to loop over all of the threads: calling `pthread_exit` from the main thread will prevent the process from terminating until all threads have exited. Also, calling `pthread_exit` from the main thread is *much* easier than using `pthread_join` for each thread. And it works if you have detached threads, too! I think it is a better solution.

Comment: @Dan, not if you want to start deleting shared resources that other threads depend on. Then you need to join first, then cleanup.

Comment: @Alex: Only if you insist on freeing them from the main thread. Otherwise, the last thread using the shared resource can free it. Also, that doesn't seem to be an issue here, or the OP would already be doing something like that.

Comment: Note that calling `pthread_exit` from all threads is not sufficient to terminate the process if the implementation internally created any threads for `SIGEV_THREAD` timers or other behind-the-scenes things. One could say such an implementation (glibc) is buggy, but since the standard declares that the lifetime of `SIGEV_THREAD` callback threads cannot be determined by the application, it's not much worse than what the standard allows. Using `exit` or returning from `main` is probably a lot safer.

Answer (score 9):

**A Tool Approach**

You can use Valgrind to help with this (via it's Helgrind tool), but it requires minor modification of the code. For each thread, you make the thread lock a unique mutex when the thread is created, and release the mutex when the thread exits. Then, when run under Helgrind, you will get a warning if the thread hasn't exited when the program terminates because the thread will still be holding the lock to the mutex. Consider this example thread start routine:

```
void * thread_start (void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // ...
    // Here the thread does whatever it normally does
    // ...

    // Unlock the mutex before exiting
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Simply run the program using Valgrind's Helgrind tool like so:

```
$ valgrind --tool=helgrind ./<program-name>
```

If the thread didn't exit when the program terminated, then Helgrind produces a warning like this:

```
==2203== Thread #2 was created
==2203==    at 0x31C96D3CDE: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==2203==    by 0x31CA206D87: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so)
==2203==    by 0x4A0B206: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:229)
==2203==    by 0x4A0B2AD: pthread_create@* (hg_intercepts.c:256)
==2203==    by 0x40060A: main (main.c:26)
==2203== 
==2203== Thread #2: Exiting thread still holds 1 lock
==2203==    at 0x4005DD: thread_start (main.c:13)
==2203==    by 0x4A0B330: mythread_wrapper (hg_intercepts.c:201)
==2203==    by 0x31CA20673C: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so)
==2203==    by 0x31C96D3D1C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
```

You will get false positives using this method if you don't add the mutex unlock code anywhere the thread may exit (e.g. using `pthread_exit`), but fixing such a false-positive is easy once it is identified.

**An Alternative Approach (Recommended)**

Having said all of the above, that's probably not the approach I myself would take. Instead, I would write the program such that it *cannot* terminate until all threads have exited. The simplest way to achieve this is to call `pthread_exit` from the main thread before returning from `main`. Doing so will mean that the process will stay alive so long as any other thread is still running.

If you take this approach, and the process doesn't quit when you expect it to, then you know that a thread is still running. You can then attach a debugger to the process to determine which threads are still running and what they are doing.

Answer (score 6):

If you plan to use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).Threads library, then you can use the `.join()` method.

[For example:](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401518;jsessionid=5L2TN2LVLRFPLQE1GHOSKHWATMY32JVN?pgno=2)

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
void hello()
{
  std::cout <<
    "Hello world, I'm a thread!"
    << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  boost::thread thrd(&hello);
  thrd.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can also join using the "C" pthreads API. See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining

Comment: -1: Pet peeve of mine: there is no such thing as C/C++. There is C and there is C++. Boost is for C++. This is a C question.

Answer (score 6):

There is a simple trick in this similar question: [Multiple threads in C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695106/multiple-threads-in-c-program)

If you call pthread_exit from main, your process will not exit until all the other threads complete.

Answer (score 4):

*Original answer was updated to address `pthread_exit()` scenario.*

Assuming you want to tell whether all threads were `pthread_join()`-ed properly *before* you return from `main()`, there are a few ways:

1. Run it under the `gdb` and break on the last line of `main()`, then look at the output of "threads" command. There should only be main thread.
2. Make a shared library that overrides `pthread_create` with a wrapper that keeps a counter of how many threads are started. Thread wrapper increments a counter and calls the actual thread function, and a function registered with `pthread_create_key()` will decrement it when a thread returns or exits. Library destructor will check if the counter is zero, which means that all of them were terminated. Use it with your executable with `LD_PRELOAD=checker.so ./your_executable` (no code modification necessary).

   Tested on Debian 5.0.5.

   ### checker.c

   ```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <pthread.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <dlfcn.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   /* thread-local storage key */
   static pthread_key_t tls_key = 0;
   static int counter = 0;
   static pthread_mutex_t g_mutex;

   /* TLS destructor prototype */
   void on_thread_end(void*);

   void __attribute__ ((constructor))
   init_checker()
   {
       pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
       pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
       pthread_mutex_init(&g_mutex, &attr);
       pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
       pthread_key_create(&tls_key, &on_thread_end);
   }

   void __attribute__ ((destructor))
   finalize_checker()
   {
       int remain;
       pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
       remain = counter;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
       pthread_mutex_destroy(&g_mutex);
       if (remain)
           fprintf(stderr, "Warning: %d threads not terminated\n", remain);
       pthread_key_delete(tls_key);
   }

   /* thread function signature */
   typedef void* (*ThreadFn)(void*);

   struct wrapper_arg
   {
       ThreadFn fn;
       void* arg;
   };

   /* TLS destructor: called for every thread we created
      when it exits */
   void
   on_thread_end(void *arg)
   {
       free(arg);
       pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
       --counter;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);
   }

   static void*
   thread_wrapper(void *arg)
   {
       void *ret;
       struct wrapper_arg *warg;

       warg = (struct wrapper_arg*)arg;

       /* Thread started, increment count. */
       pthread_mutex_lock(&g_mutex);
       ++counter;
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_mutex);

       /* set thread-specific data to avoid leaks
        * when thread exits
        */
       pthread_setspecific(tls_key, arg);

       /* Run the actual function. */
       ret = (*warg->fn)(warg->arg);

       /* Thread finishes, TLS destructor will be called. */

       return ret;
   }

   /* pthread_create signature */
   typedef int (*CreateFn)(pthread_t*,const pthread_attr_t*,ThreadFn,void*);

   /* Overriding phtread_create */
   int
   pthread_create(
       pthread_t *thread,
       const pthread_attr_t *attr,
       ThreadFn start_routine,
       void *arg)
   {
       CreateFn libc_pthread_create;
       struct wrapper_arg *warg;

       /* Get a handle to the real function. */
       libc_pthread_create
           = (CreateFn)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");
       if (!libc_pthread_create)
           return -1;

       /* Wrap user function. */
       warg = malloc(sizeof(struct wrapper_arg));
       if (!warg)
           return -1;
       warg->fn = start_routine;
       warg->arg = arg;

       /* Create a thread with a wrapper. */
       return libc_pthread_create(thread, attr, &thread_wrapper, warg);
   }
   ```

   ### Makefile

   ```
   CFLAGS+=-fpic -O3
   checker.so: checker.o
       gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@ $^ -ldl -lpthread
   ```

Comment: This doesn't quite work unless you also provide a way to decrement the thread count from places where threads exit without returning from the thread start routine (e.g. what if a thread calls `pthread_exit`?)

Comment: @Dan, hmm, you are correct, even though it's not a preferred method, there is a technical possibility. I suspect there should be a TLS-based solution for this...

Comment: @Alex-B I like this approach (+1). But I was wondering if there's anyway of implementing a similar approach with static linking ?

Comment: @msalvadores This works in similar way if you link statically, except DSO constructor/destructor bit. You will have to init/destroy manually. But hey, if you are modifying your build process, might as well add two lines to your code.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if wrong, but a program is not finished until all running threads have ended.

Comment: Not true. It is not documented (I think) how pthreads terminates. But in the ones I have used if the main thread (the created by the OS) exits then all threads are terminated automatically. This is why you should wait for all child threads to finish before you let main() exit. Which is what the question is about.

Comment: @Martin, this is correct. I just want to be sure that everything has been cleanup before main exits. Valgrind is for memory leak, I was searching for a tool that can check that all threads have been terminated successfully. Thanks.

Comment: @robUK You should update your question with this more specific information.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any external tool for this: i would track the threads by using a simple **semaphore** instead.

1) set it up so that its initial count is the same as the number of your threads:

```
sem_init( &semThreadCount, 0, threadCount );
```

2) Modify your threads to "notify" they are exiting gracefully:

```
sem_wait( &semThreadCount );
```

3) You can either quit whenever the threads are finished or when the semaphore is 0, or just print the remaining semaphore value and quit, that will be the number of still-running threads:

```
int v;
sem_getvalue( &semThreadCount, &v );
```

This way you can both ensure no threads are still running if your exit or, with some logging, being able to know which ones are still running after you quit.

Remember to `sem_destroy` the sempahore as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not use C++ and therefore KMan's answer, then you can also join detached pthreads using the "C" API. (Joining means to wait for the detached threads to finish their work.)

See the [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining).

Answer (score 1):

The existance of the process, that is if there is any thread still running, can be checked with `waitpid`.

If you just want your process to continue with all the threads, but you don't need the one of `main` anymore you can end that thread by `pthread_exit`. Other than an explicit `exit` or a simple `return` this will not terminate your other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Such tools already exists. On Linux you can use `ps` or `top`. On Windows, good ole Task Manager does the job:. Just check whether your process still exists:

- if the process still exists, it means that one or more threads in it are running.
- if there are no more threads running, the process is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

If they're threads (rather than processes) then you just need to check for your process stll running because threads run inside a process.

You can check if a process is running with ps -ef then pipe the result into grep to find your specific process.

Comment: May be he wants to ensure all threads created have exited before the main exits. Probably he wants to do some clean up in all threads and write something to a database/file for the new launch. Anyways its just a guess.

Comment: @Praveen, that is correct. I just want to make sure all threads finished successfully before main exits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an external means to observe the threads in execution for your process, on Linux you can look in /proc/(pid)/task.  That's the method tools like ps(1) or top(1) use.

See http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out on the important part:

**A program cannot exit unless all its threads are terminated**.

What you should do, however, is [`pthread_join()`](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/3:pthread_join) on all the threads before exiting. This ensures that all threads terminated, and will allow you to `free()` all their respective `pthread_t`s, so that you do not leak memory from them.

Have that said, `valgrind` can give you a comprehensive view on threads you haven't cleaned up after. Run it with `--leakcheck=full` and make sure you are not leaving various structs behind you. Those will indicate there is a thread you haven't completely terminated properly.